# Android: Change canvas clipBounds

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to to draw a custom slider which has a tooltip that fades in and out on touch events. I am having trouble with the canvas clip bounds. The tooltip is placed above the slider, giving it negative canvas coordinates, which should be fine since I replace the clip bounds on every OnDraw.

When running on a Lenovo tablet it works just as expected, but on the Google Nexus 7 something odd happens. The clip bound are only acknowledged the very first OnDraw (I have tried filling the canvas with a solid color just to see its size) and after that, even though debugging says the clipBounds are correct, everything outside the original clipbounds are clipped.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?